# i am getting ajax response slow

Tags: php, html, ajax

i am using the following code for pass and get data through ajax.

```
function passdata(id) 
{


    var top = document.getElementById("tname").value;
    var first = document.getElementById("fname").value;

    var font_top = document.getElementById("font_top").value;
    var font_first = document.getElementById("font_first").value;

    var image_top = document.getElementById("image_top").value;
    var image_first = document.getElementById("image_first").value;


var poststr = "id=" + id +
"&top=" + top +
"&first=" + first +
"&font_top=" + font_top +
"&font_first=" + font_first +
"&image_top=" + image_top +
"&image_first=" + image_first +
"&actype=getevent"; 

var reqAddCart = new Subsys_JsHttpRequest_Js();

reqAddCart.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (reqAddCart.readyState == 4) {
if (reqAddCart.responseJS) {
document.location.href = reqAddCart.responseJS.ajax_redirect;
return;
}
else {
 //alert(reqAddCart.responseText); 
//showModal('abc');

document.getElementById('data_content').innerHTML = reqAddCart.responseText; 


result = (reqAddCart.responseText||'');

var brokenresult=result.split("@");

}
}
}
var senddata = new Object();

var url = 'product.php?'+poststr; 
//alert(url);

reqAddCart.caching = false;
reqAddCart.open( 'GET', url, true);
reqAddCart.send( senddata );

return false;
}
```

i am using the passdata function to pass the data in product page.this function works but i am getting response very slow.

Comment: Post only the relevant code please. And your problem is most likely on the server (slow response time from your script).

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to read trough that chunk of code. Please cut it down a bit to the relevant parts. And have you made sure it's no the servers response that's slow?

Comment: yes may be it is possible because on development server it works perfectly but on live i am getting very slow respose..so how can i reslove this on server?

Comment: Again, post some relevant code, tell us all the relevant bitss about your server&setup etc etc

Comment: Ajax will wait until the script you call ends its execution, THEN it will display it's results (callback function). So if the AJAX call is slow, it just means the script you are calling is slow!

Comment: @Naryl if my scripts are slow then why it is working perfectly on development server.i got response very quick on development server.this issue is occur on live server.

Comment: Because live server is different from dev - you have network latency, concurrent requests, maybe it's a 80486 who knows.

Answer (score 0):

The time taken for an AJAX request to complete is affected by network latency and connection speed on both the server and client, as well as execution time of the script on the server.

I would expect AJAX requests made locally when testing to return a lot faster as it removes the need for transmitting data over the internet.